# How can I add a column which is a sum of another comma-delimited chr column?

Tags: r

Given this data frame:

```
> seq <- as.character(c("1, 2, 3", "4, 5", NA, "6"))
> my.df <- data.frame(seq, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> str(my.df)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ seq: chr  "1, 2, 3" "4, 5" NA "6"
> my.df
      seq
1 1, 2, 3
2    4, 5
3    <NA>
4       6
```

How can I write code to add a column which is a sum of the first column?

```
      seq my.sum
1 1, 2, 3      6
2    4, 5      9
3    <NA>     NA
4       6      6
> str(my.df)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ seq   : chr  "1, 2, 3" "4, 5" NA "6"
 $ my.sum: num  6 9 NA 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution where we can `strsplit()` the `seq` column to a list of character vectors and then use `sapply()` to sum up each vector in the list:

```
my.df$my.sum <- sapply(strsplit(my.df$seq, ", "), function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))

my.df
#      seq my.sum
#1 1, 2, 3      6
#2    4, 5      9
#3    <NA>     NA
#4       6      6
```